# Error displayed when installation of bitnami-gitlab

Tags: gitlab, bitnami

I get the following error when I run: `bitnami-gitlab.run`

> Error copying file from packed /data/software/bitnamigitlab.run to
>       /opt/gitlab-8.4.2-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4/ext/charlock_holmes/dst/share/misc/magic.mgc
>       :Insufficient Disk Space

Why does this happen and how can it be solved?

Answer (score 0):

The `Insufficient Disk Space` line kind of tells me that you do not have enough free space in your disk. Are you sure you have enough space? Delete something else and retry, or get a bigger disk/partition.